# In PowerPoint, how do I combine two Slide Masters with different Slide Sizes?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have two Slide Masters that I want in a single PowerPoint deck. Each Slide Master has a different Slide Size (either Standard or Widescreen)  For solid color Layouts, this is not a problem. For slides that have artwork, either one Slide Master is compressed or the other one is stretched horizontally.

How can I use combine both slide masters in a single deck? I inherited these slides from different colleagues and I don't have access to the original artwork or files.

Thanks,

Gwen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple slide sizes in a single PowerPoint file, it's not possible.

If you're looking to combine slides of different sizes into a single deck, you'll need some variant on:

```
Find a slide (or master) that contains distorted graphics. 
Delete the distorted graphics. 
Select and copy the same (undistorted) graphics from the original file. 
Paste into the new file. 
Size/position the newly pasted graphics as needed.
```

If your original slides have their background fill set as images, you'll need to add a duplicate of the slide, delete everything on the slide, leaving just the background image, then export the slide as a PNG. In the new presentation, locate the same slide and remove the picture background fill, then insert the exported PNG as a picture and center/size to taste, send to back.